# Limiting the number of interstitial ads

Tags: android, interstitial

When I add interstitial in oncreate of activity (not main activity) ads loading each time user open that activity

I need a code that show interstitial once when open a activity and if this activity opens again and again doesn't show any ads

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
public static final String EXTRA_POI_ID = "poi_id";
public static final String EXTRA_POI_LATITUDE = "poi_latitude";
public static final String EXTRA_POI_LONGITUDE = "poi_longitude";


public static Intent newIntent(Context context)
{
    return new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);
}


public static Intent newIntent(Context context, long poiId, double poiLatitude, double poiLongitude)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);

    // extras
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POI_ID, poiId);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POI_LATITUDE, poiLatitude);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POI_LONGITUDE, poiLongitude);

    return intent;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    setupActionBar();
    //Dgad.setTest(true);
    Dgad.showRandomPopup(MapActivity.this);

    // init analytics tracker
    ((CityGuideApplication) getApplication()).getTracker();
}


@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    // analytics
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    // analytics
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // action bar menu behaviour
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


private void setupActionBar()
{
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Just keep a flag, possibly in your Application class

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing this :

```
end_ad=new InterstitialAd(this);
end_ad.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
end_ad.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

When you want to controle it :

```
if(end_ad.isLoaded()){
   end_ad.show();
   Log.d(TAG,"SHOWING");
}
else{
   Log.d(TAG, "NOT SHOWING");
}
```

Otherwise, you can create a `GlobalConstantClass`

```
public GlobalClass{
 public static boolean Shown = false;
}
```

Then when you show the ADS for first time you can put this `boolean` to true:

```
GlobalClass.Shown = true;
```

And if you want to show it when you close the app in the `onDestroy()`, you set the variable to `false`

Then at the time you want to show the ADDS you have to ask for this `boolean`, for example :

```
if(!GlobalClass.Shown){
 //Show adds
 Dgad.showRandomPopup(MapActivity.this);
 GlobalClass.Shown=true;
}
else {
 //Do nothing
}
```

Comment: @saadat68 let me know if it solved your answer please... otherwise I'll try to update it, or if it helped mark this answer as a correct :)

Comment: Post the activity that you want to add this code(java)

Comment: Thanks. I add it to my first post. for example a blank activity

Comment: Dgad.showRandomPopup(MapActivity.this); //this is interstitial code

Comment: And you just want to show it once? You mean tjat thats thr metod to show the ads?

Comment: Follow the steps that I proposed to you, first create a new java class, then create on it a static boolean and a sign it to false then on your map activity where you show the ads copy the code of my answer and it would work.